# X,Y, Z are independent then $X+Z$ and $Y+Z$ are independent

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

Here is my question, I’m not sure how to prove what I have in mind:

If $X$,$Y$, $Z$ are independent then are $X+Z$ and $Y+Z$ also independent ?

I can't decide whether the above statement is true , let alone prove it.

We say that $X,Y$ are independent when $p_{X,Y}(x,y) =p_{X}(x)p_{Y}(y)$

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your working definition of "independent"?

Comment: @aschepler added!

Comment: the easiest way to check that is to calculate the correlation of (x + z) and (y + z) and see if its non-zero. Zero isn't a sufficient condition for them not being correlated ( there could be a non-linear relationship )  but a non-zero value tells that they are linearly correlated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true. Consider the following simple example:

Experiment: Tossing a fair coin once.

Sample Space: $S = \{H, T\}$

Define random variables $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ as

- $X(s)=0$ $\forall s \in S$
- $Y(s)=0$ $\forall s \in S$
- $Z(H)=1$ and $Z(T)=0$

Clearly, $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are independent because
$p_{X,Y,Z}(a,b,c) = p_X(a)p_Y(b)p_Z(c) = \begin{cases} p_Z(c) &\text{if } a= 0, b = 0, c \in\{0,1\} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

But $X+Z=Z$ and $Y+Z =Z$ are not independent. This because
$p_{X+Z, Y+Z}(0,0) =p_{Z, Z}(0,0) = p_Z(0) = \frac{1}{2} \neq \frac{1}{4} =  p_Z(0)p_Z(0) = p_{X+Z}(0)p_{Y+Z}(0)$

Comment: Simple, example? Look at my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Take $X=0,Y=0$  and $Z$ any non-constant r.v.  Then $X,Y,Z$ are  independent but $Z=X+Z$ and $Z=Y+Z$ are not independent.