# $\textbf{x},\textbf{y},\textbf{z}$ are d dimensional gaussian random variables then $\textbf{x}+\textbf{y}, \textbf{x}+\textbf{z}$ are independent

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, independence

How do we prove following statement,

> $\textbf{x},\textbf{y},\textbf{z} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2 I)$ are d dimensional gaussian random
> variables with identity covariance, then $\textbf{x}+\textbf{y}, \textbf{x}+\textbf{z}$ are
> independent

First is the above statement true?, cause in full generality it doesn't hold true :  [X,Y, Z are independent then $X+Z$ and $Y+Z$ are independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4474406/x-y-z-are-independent-then-xz-and-yz-are-independent)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't prove it, it's false.

Comment: @J.G. how do we see  this ?

Comment: Hint: compute the covariance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the conditions stated, $X+Z$ and $Y+Z$ are not independent.

Here is why:

$$\text{Cov}(X+Z,Y+Z)=\text{Cov}(X,Y)+\text{Cov}(X,Z)+\text{Cov}(Y,Z)+\text{Cov}(Z,Z)$$

Because $X,Y,Z\sim \text{Multivariate Normal}(\mathbf{0},\sigma^2 I)$
$$\text{Cov}(X,Y)=\text{Cov}(X,Z)=\text{Cov}(Y,Z)=0\ \ \text{and}\ \ \text{Cov}(Z,Z)=\sigma^2,$$
leading to
$$\text{Cov}(X+Z,Y+Z)=\sigma^2.$$
As independence implies zero covariance, if $\sigma^2>0$, $X+Z$ and $Y+Z$ are not independent.